# Draggable threejs not working

Tags: three.js

I was working on a threejs where a scene is loaded and on dbl click a mesh component is added. I am trying to drag this across the screen so i refered https://threejs.org/examples/?q=drag#webgl_interactive_draggablecubes

```
$(document).on('addRectangle', function(d){
var sphere = new THREE.BoxGeometry(6,20,6);
var objectMesh = new THREE.Mesh( sphere, new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( {color:0xff0000,visible:true} ));
scene.add(objectMesh);
objectMeshs.push(objectMesh);
var dragControls = new THREE.DragControls( objectMeshs, getCameraControl().activeCamera,renderer.domElement);
dragControls.addEventListener( 'dragstart', function ( event )  
controls.enabled = false; 
} );
dragControls.addEventListener( 'dragend', function ( event ) { controls.enabled = true; } );
needRefresh = true;
});
```

But when proceed with double click it says client.js:51358 Uncaught TypeError: _raycaster.setFromCamera is not a function at HTMLCanvasElement.onDocumentMouseMove

Comment: The error is telling you where the problem is, but you did not include the associated code. Look in your `mousemove` event listener to see why it might be saying `setFromCamera` is not a function.